# VB.net API variables

Tags: vb.net

I really hope someone can help me with this, I've searched everywhere and can't find anything on the matter.
I've got a SMART card printer that prints plastic cards and I've been given the API to interact with it directly from vb.net, I've managed to execute most of the functions but one of them refers to a

```
1   COLORREF
```

and a

```
1   WCHAR*
```

variable and I'm clueless as to what they want me to provide.

Below is the structure I've been given for context

```
01  int SmartComm_DrawBarcode(
02  HSMART hHandle,
03  BYTE page,
04  BYTE panel,
05  int x,
06  int y,
07  int cx,
08  int cy,
09  COLORREF col,
10  RECT* prcArea,
11  const WCHAR* szName,
12  int nSize,
13  const WCHAR* szData,
14  const WCHAR* szPost
15  );
```

Below is the code that I'm using to execute one of the functions and it works perfectly, I just can't get the barcode working:

```
1   Dim lclogo As String = "C:\acer\lclogo.png"
2           strImg_ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(LunchcardLogo)
3           rcDraws_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(RECT)))
4           If nres = SM_SUCCESS Then
5               nres = SmartComm_DrawImage(hsmart, CByte(PAGE_FRONT), CByte(PANEL_BLACK), 606, 456, 405, 171, strImg_ptr, rcDraws_ptr)
6           End If
7    
8           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(strImg_ptr)
9           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(rcDraws_ptr)
```

*I know that the original structure is in either c# or c++ but I can't for the life of me find the equivalent in vb.net.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you try to stand on 'COLORREF' and hit the F12 button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A COLORREF is basically a 32bit integer value. You can define a struct to interact with it like this (see this [link](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COLORREF.html) for details):

```
Structure COLORREF 
  Public R As Byte
  Public G As Byte
  Public B As Byte

  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return String.Format("({0},{1},{2})", R, G, B)
  End Function
End Structure
```

WCHAR* is a pointer to a wide-character string. So you can use String as its data type and add the [MarshalAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
WCHAR* szName
```

will be

```
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> szName As String
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you give me an example of the data you would send as a colorref? When I try something like "0X0000112" it rejects it.

Comment: Thank you so much! All sorted.